# Pycharm - force synchronizing to be more often/quicker

Tags: pycharm

I have Pycharm 2017.1 and large Django application with many lines of code. **I use vagrant so it can be reason of slow performance (is there any way to speed up it?)** Pycharm doesn't work well with it, because of many large modules.

When i changing something in code syntax errors are still highlighed after about 5 minutes after i fix this errors.
Automatic imports are often not performed and if i forget to import something it is detected by PyCharm very late.

It is impossible to refactor this code :)

I know that there is something like "synchronize" option but it not help. Perhaps it works for small projects but in my project synchronization takes too much time.
Also "refresh" option don't help.

Is there any way to speed up this synchronization? Perhaps some change in configuration? Any ideas?

Comment: You never mentioned which OS are you using? Which Vagrant version and which VirtualBox version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS vagrant 1.9.7 and virtualbox: 5.0.40 _Ubuntur115130

Comment: Can you use `config.vm.synced_folder "<source>", "<dest>", type: "nfs",
 mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp'],
 linux__nfs_options: ['rw','no_subtree_check','all_squash','async']` in your `Vagrantfile` and see if it helps? This is not a pycharm issue but rather a NFS mount setting issue with Vagrant

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, it helps. but time interval beetween import and disappearance of red underline under imported class name is still large. I also increased limits in and it works OK. Please createw answer instead of comment because i want to grant bounty for your help and it expires today. If you have any other ideas to improve performance please add them to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `config.vm.synced_folder "<source>", "<dest>", type: "nfs",
 mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp'],
 linux__nfs_options: ['rw','no_subtree_check','all_squash','async']` in your `Vagrantfile` and see if it helps? This is not a pycharm issue but rather a NFS mount setting issue with Vagrant